# Subtract value from previous value with exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some calculations where a normal LAG function would solve it for me, which Ive tried. However. My question comes with an exception.
Every january and july the value resets to 1500. On row nr 2 I need to subtract the value but with row nr 1 (this is where LAG comes in). This works but I dont know how to solve it with exception for july and then january again. See picture

[image]

Code I've worked with

```
SELECT 
SUM(ts.[HOURS]) as HOURS
,FORMAT(ts.STARTDATE, 'yyyyMM') as YearMonth
,YEAR(ts.STARTDATE) as Year
,MONTH(ts.STARTDATE) as Month
,LAG(SUM(ts.[HOURS])) OVER(ORDER BY FORMAT(ts.STARTDATE, 'yyyyMM') ) as lag
--,IIF(MONTH(ts.STARTDATE) = 1 OR MONTH(ts.STARTDATE) = 7, 1500 - SUM(ts.[HOURS]), SUM(ts.HOURS)) as tidkvar
,LEAD(SUM(ts.[HOURS])) OVER(ORDER BY FORMAT(ts.STARTDATE, 'yyyyMM') ) as lead
FROM [dbo].[TimesheetLines] AS ts
WHERE ts.PROJECTID = '70000196.01.02' OR ts.PROJECTID = '70000196.02.02' OR ts.PROJECTID = '70000013.02'
GROUP BY FORMAT(ts.STARTDATE, 'yyyyMM'), YEAR(ts.STARTDATE), MONTH(ts.STARTDATE)
Order by YearMonth
```

After the answer below I tried

```
SELECT
--SUM(ts.HOURS)
FORMAT(ts.STARTDATE, 'yyyyMM') YearMonth
,1500 - sum(ts.HOURS) over (partition by year(ts.STARTDATE), (month(ts.STARTDATE) - 1) / 6 order by ts.STARTDATE) as TimmarKvar
FROM FactTSTimesheetLines_UNPIVOT as ts
WHERE ts.PROJECTID IN ('70000196.01.02','70000196.02.02','70000013.02')
GROUP BY FORMAT(ts.STARTDATE, 'yyyyMM'), ts.STARTDATE, ts.HOURS
Order by YearMonth
```

But I get error message that HOURS is not in an aggregate function nor GROUP BY. I added HOURS to GROUP BY but that obviously gives me rows per hour which is undesired

Comment: Are you really storing the dates as month strings, or you have real `date` datatype?

Comment: You need year information too.

Comment: Pls see edited post for code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the months into groups and used a CTE to SUM for each group. Although Gordons answer is much simplier.  Such as:

```
CREATE TABLE #Work (StartDate date, HOURS int)
INSERT INTO #Work
    VALUES ('1/1/2019', 132),
            ('2/1/2019',258),
            ('3/1/2019',201),
            ('4/1/2019',181),
            ('5/1/2019',85),
            ('6/1/2019',186),
            ('7/1/2019',6),
            ('8/1/2019',156),
            ('9/1/2019',240),
            ('10/1/2019',419),
            ('11/1/2019',335),
            ('12/1/2019',109),
            ('1/1/2020',179),
            ('2/1/2020',228),
            ('3/1/2020',97)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
    SUM(ts.[HOURS]) as HOURS
    ,FORMAT(ts.STARTDATE, 'yyyyMM') as YearMonth
    ,YEAR(ts.STARTDATE) as Year
    ,MONTH(ts.STARTDATE) as Month
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ts.STARTDATE) IN (1,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY YEAR(ts.STARTDATE), MONTH(ts.STARTDATE)) GRP
    FROM #Work AS ts
    GROUP BY FORMAT(ts.STARTDATE, 'yyyyMM'), YEAR(ts.STARTDATE), MONTH(ts.STARTDATE), ts.HOURS
)
SELECT * ,
1500 -  SUM(HOURS) OVER(PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY MONTH) Total
from CTE
Order by YearMonth
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a date, you can use a cumulative sum and subtraction.  But you need to put the data in groups.  One simple method is to use `month()` and `year()`:

```
select t.*,
       (1500 -
        sum(col1) over (partition by year(datecol), (month(datecol) - 1) / 6 order by datecol)
       )
from t;
```

I've used column names that I can spell on my keyboard.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c29b2d9d4c1cf2619235a557895fd64) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @CobraKaj . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  It looks correct.